# Greedy Algorithm problem: how to assign workers with different skillsets to jobs

Tags: optimization, greedy

I'm trying to write an algorithm to optimize my performance in the smartphone game Tiny Tower.

I have "n" workers.

There are 5 types of stores: store_types=['green', 'blue', 'yellow', 'purple', 'orange'].

i have "k[i]" spaces open in each type of store.

Each worker has a skillset: a score (0-9) for each type of store, where 9 is most skilled.

for example, workers[3] might have a name and skillset ['randy',9,6,7,6,3], each score number corresponding to a type of store.

I might have k=[11,15,9,20,5] spaces open, each number corresponding to the spaces open for each type of store.

I want to place my workers in jobs that optimize my overall performance. Like, if a worker has a score 9 in green stores, I want them in a green store. And so on.

Also, I might have too many workers or too many open positions, so if that's the case, unemployed workers or open job positions are okay (I don't want algorithm to crash due to it).

I already have set up a user-input process to obtain:

- list of workers and their info that looks like [['washington', 9, 8, 8, 9, 6], ['lawson', 6, 2, 9, 9, 2],......]
  (i.e. lawson has a score of 6 for green jobs)
- list of number of spaces available in each type of store that looks like [11, 9, 12, 9, 12]
  (i.e. 11 spaces available in green stores)

I don't know what to do next to optimize job assignments. I've googled around a lot about Greedy Algorithm stuff but I'm really just not sure how to go about this.
Pseudocode or conceptual steps are enough for me to work with. Thank you!

(This is for fun, not school or work. I've been coding for 4 years and I'm new to Stack Overflow, please excuse me if I missed any Stack Overflow etiquette.)

Answer (score 0):

Surely you have read the Wikipedia page [Greedy algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm) and are aware that *a greedy algorithm never reconsiders its choices*, having the disadvantage that it might *not produce an optimal solution* and the advantage that *it terminates in a reasonable number of steps* and is *quick to think up*.

So, here's pseudocode (which happens to be executable Python code) that assigns each worker in order to a still open job where the skill is highest:

```
for worker in workers:
    name = worker.pop(0)    # extract the first list element
    # tie the store index to the score:
    worker = [(score, index) for index, score in enumerate(worker)]
    while worker:
        score, store = max(worker)  # high score
        if k[store]:
            k[store] -= 1
            print(name, store_types[store])
            break
        else:   # remove store with no open space from worker's skillset:
            worker.remove((score, store))
    else:   print(name, 'unemployed')
```